# Enum type error C2677

Tags: c++, enums, sdl

my problem is, i got this enum type declared in my Button.h file:

```
enum ButtonEnum
    {
        BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_RED = 0,
        BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_VIOLET = 1,
        BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_DBLUE = 2,
        BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_GREY = 3,
        BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_DGREEN = 4,
        BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_LBLUE = 5,
        BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_LGREEN = 6,
        BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_YELLOW = 7,
        BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_EMPTY = 8,
        BUTTON_SPRITE_TOTAL = 9
    };
```

Later, i declare this:

```
ButtonEnum mCurrentSprite;
```

and use it in other function in Button.cpp:

```
void Button::render()
{
    SDLFunctions::render(mPosition.x,mPosition.y,SDLFunctions::gSpriteClips[mCurrentSprite] );
}
```

SDLFunctions::render looks like that:

```
void SDLFunctions::render( int x, int y, SDL_Rect* clip )
{
    //Set rendering space and render to screen
SDL_Rect renderQuad = { x, y, mWidth, mHeight };

//Set clip rendering dimensions
if( clip != NULL )
{
    renderQuad.w = clip->w;
    renderQuad.h = clip->h;
}

//Render to screen
SDL_RenderCopy( gRenderer, mTexture, clip, &renderQuad );
}
```

and SDLFunctions::gSpriteClips is this:

```
SDL_Rect gSpriteClips[ 9 ];
```

which in another function is filled with some values.
To the point. Building program results with this:
error C2677: binary '[' : no global operator found which takes type 'Button::ButtonEnum' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

And my question is: what the hell? What is wrong with this? mCurrentSprite got declared starting value in builder, and everytime Button::render is called, it got some value, its not NULL. Can someone solve it? Thanks.

Comment: C2677 is a microsoft VC specific error. Could you add your Visual C++ version as tag to your question?

Comment: also, errors usually have something like line numbers attached to them. It doesn't seem like you're having the line where that error occurred in your question, or you did not clearly state whether the `render` function is where it happens

Comment: Write `SDLFunctions::gSpriteClips[static_cast<size_t> (mCurrentSprite)]` to fix it.

Comment: Marcus:
It's Visual Studio Professional 2012. "render" function is in Button.cpp file, and right there error occurs.
Ruslan:
it didnt helped, it only caused these errors, all in the same place, in "render" function:
error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'SDLFunctions::gSpriteClips'
error C3867: 'SDLFunctions::gSpriteClips': function call missing argument list; use '&SDLFunctions::gSpriteClips' to create a pointer to member
error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compiler is trying to tell you (in a very unclear way) that you are indexing into an array using an enum.  That's not really allowed--enums have integral values, but they aren't integer types.  So you need to cast it:

```
SDLFunctions::render(mPosition.x, mPosition.y,
    SDLFunctions::gSpriteClips[static_cast<size_t>(mCurrentSprite)]);
```

Comment: Just like in comment above, it didnt helped, it only caused these errors, all in the same place, in "render" function: 
     error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'SDLFunctions::gSpriteClips'
     error C3867: 'SDLFunctions::gSpriteClips': function call missing argument list; use '&SDLFunctions::gSpriteClips' to create a pointer to member
     error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type